# Facing the DllNotFoundException with SkiaSharp.dll while converting the document as a PDF after using the hosted AWS service path

Tags: aws-lambda, pdf-generation, http-status-code-500, skiasharp, dllnotfoundexception

We have deployed the ASP.NET Core Web API with AWS Lambda. While using the hosted AWS service path in the fetch API to invoke the server for saving the document as pdf processing, we faced the problem "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()**" on the client side. While validating this problem in the AWS log, we found that the **DllNotFoundException** occurred with SkiaSharp.dll on the AWS server side. Then we installed **SkiaSharp.dll** properly on our server end. After installing SkiaSharp.dll, we published the AWS lambda and ensured the installed SkiaSharp.dll was included in the published folder as well. But even after installing SkiaSharp.dll, the same exception still occurred on our end.

[Exception error image added here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prg3Z.png)

Even after installing SkiaSharp.dll, the same DllNotFoundException occurred with SkiaSharp.dll on the AWS server side. **Our requirement is to save our document as a pdf** by using our client and server-side codes. So, we expect a solution to resolve this exception problem and a suggestion to save the document as a pdf.